# How to insert value to specific cell in array in Python?

Tags: python, arrays

I need to get 10 numbers from the user, and than calc the amount of times each digit is appear in all the numbers.

I wrote the next code:

```
# Reset variable
aUserNum=[]
aDigits=[]

# Ask the user for 10 numbers
for i in range(0,2,1):
    iNum = int(input("Please enter your number: "))
    aUserNum.append(iNum)

# Reset aDigits array
for i in range(0,10,1):
    aDigits.append(0)

# Calc the count of each digit
for i in range(0,2,1):
    iNum=aUserNum[i]
    print("a[i] ",aUserNum[i])
    while (iNum!=0):
        iLastNum=iNum%10
        temp=aDigits[iLastNum]+1
        aDigits.insert(iLastNum,temp)
        iNum=iNum//10

print(aDigits)
```

from the result, I can see that the temp is not working.
When I write this temp=aDigits[iLastNum]+1, Shouldn't it say that the array in cell iLastNum will get the value of the cell +1?

thanks,
Yaniv

Comment: Tip: `range(0, 10, 1) == range(10)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can concatenate all the inputs to get a single string and use this with `collections.Counter()`

```
import collections
ct = collections.Counter("1234567890123475431234")
ct['3'] == 4
ct.most_common() # gives a list of tuples, ordered by times of occurrence
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this two ways.  Either with strings, or with integers.

```
aUserNum = []

# Make testing easier
debug = True

if debug:
    aUserNum = [55, 3303, 565, 55665, 565789]
else:
    for i in range(10):
        iNum = int(input("Please enter your number: "))
        aUserNum.append(iNum)
```

With strings, we turn all of the integers into a big string, and then count how many occurances of '0' there are, and then how many '1's there are, etc.

```
def string_count(nums):
    # Make a long string with all the numbers stuck together
    s = ''.join(map(str, nums))

    # Make all of the digits into strings
    n = ''.join(map(str, range(10)))

    aDigits = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

    for i, x in enumerate(n):
        aDigits[i] = s.count(x)

    return aDigits
```

With integers we can use the lovely trick of integer division.  This code is written for Python 2.7, and won't work on 3.x because of the "assume float" change.  To get around that change the `x /= 10` to `x //= 10` and change the print statements to print functions.

```
def num_count(nums):
    aDigits = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

    for x in nums:
        while x:
            # Add a count for the digit in the ones place
            aDigits[x % 10] += 1

            # Then chop off the ones place, until integer division results in 0
            # and the loop ends
            x /= 10

    return aDigits
```

These output the same.

```
print string_count(aUserNum)
print num_count(aUserNum)
# [1, 0, 0, 3, 0, 9, 4, 1, 1, 1]
```

For prettier output, write it like this.

```
print list(enumerate(string_count(aUserNum)))
print list(enumerate(num_count(aUserNum)))
# [(0, 1), (1, 0), (2, 0), (3, 3), (4, 0), (5, 9), (6, 4), (7, 1), (8, 1), (9, 1)]
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but becuase I'm new in python I don't understand most of what you wrote.
Is there a way to fix my code?

Comment: I successed :)
I fixed my code based what you wrote.
thank you